# Pyodbc not installing in Docker image

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, pyodbc

I'm trying to use a Docker image with SQLAlchemy, which have dependencies with pyodbc. I'm trying to get the package installed from the Dockerfile, but I'm not finding the solution anywhere.

Right now, the basic structure of the directory could be like this:

```
root
| notebooks
| |testAlchemy.ipynb
| Dockerfile
| docker-compose.yml
| requirements.txt
```

Here are the contents of requirements.txt:

```
ipython-sql
pyodbc
psycopg2
sqlalchemy
```

Here my dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

VOLUME /notebooks

WORKDIR /notebooks
```

And here the docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    build:
      context: ./jupyter
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=1234
    volumes:
      - "./notebooks:/notebooks"
      - "./data:/data"

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passw
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Then I do `docker compose up` and connect to jupyter server
In the notebook I have a really simple code:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection_string = f"DATABASE=operational;UID=user;PWD=passw;HOST=postgres"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

But every time I try to run this code I get this error:
[moduleNotFoundError img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA4Vm.png)

And obviously, if I run `!pip list` in the notebook, `pyodbc` doesn't show anywhere. But I can run `!pip install pyodbc` with no problem

I'm sure I'm doing something  wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: Try to build the Dockerfile first and check if there is any error message related to pyodbc.   Add `apt install gcc` to dockerfile and check if works

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either, I get the same error. Thanx anyway

Comment: @wildBass Are you running this code outside the docker environments or inside one of the containers?

Comment: @IanWilson, inside the jupyter container. 
I have everything in VSC,
Then I open the terminal and do "docker build ."
Then I do docker compose up
Then I go to localhost:8888 to connect with jupyter. 
Then I execute the cell on that notebook (testAlchemy.ipynb)
And I get the error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this recipe from their site, linked below, this is the CONDA+requirements file version:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} connect.py "/home/${NB_USER}"
COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} requirements.txt /tmp/
#RUN pip install --quiet --no-cache-dir --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt && \
#    fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
#    fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"
RUN mamba install --yes --file /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    mamba clean --all -f -y && \
    fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
    fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"

VOLUME /notebooks

WORKDIR /notebooks
```

[using-mamba-install-or-pip-install-in-a-child-docker-image](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#using-mamba-install-or-pip-install-in-a-child-docker-image)

Output

```
$ docker build --no-cache . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  42.06MB
Step 1/8 : FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
 ---> 03fcab0a8478
Step 2/8 : USER root
 ---> Running in a064e6e68110
Removing intermediate container a064e6e68110
 ---> f1681b20edb3
Step 3/8 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential &&     apt-get clean && rm -rf var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 4622166e35a4
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [767 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1,792 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [614 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,642 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [522 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [573 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [8,056 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [914 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [952 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7,275 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [3,175 B]
Fetched 24.7 MB in 5s (5,102 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
build-essential is already the newest version (12.9ubuntu3).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpq5 libssl-dev
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc-14 libssl-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpq-dev libpq5 libssl-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,659 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [140 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7 [2,372 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpq-dev amd64 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [147 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 2,659 kB in 1s (2,739 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libpq5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 49774 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpq5_14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq5:amd64 (14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libpq-dev_14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq-dev (14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libpq5:amd64 (14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up libpq-dev (14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing intermediate container 4622166e35a4
 ---> 1c46f27c2516
Step 4/8 : COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} connect.py "/home/${NB_USER}"
 ---> acab4c589e51
Step 5/8 : COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} requirements.txt /tmp/
 ---> 3b506e4bdd02
Step 6/8 : RUN mamba install --yes --file /tmp/requirements.txt &&     mamba clean --all -f -y &&     fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" &&     fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"
 ---> Running in ced464550b21
Transaction

  Prefix: /opt/conda

  Updating specs:

   - ipython-sql
   - pyodbc
   - psycopg2
   - sqlalchemy
   - ca-certificates
   - certifi
   - openssl


  Package        Version  Build            Channel                   Size
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Install:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  + ipython-sql    0.3.9  pyhd8ed1ab_1004  conda-forge/noarch        19kB
  + libpq           14.5  he2d8382_1       conda-forge/linux-64       3MB
  + prettytable    3.4.1  pyhd8ed1ab_0     conda-forge/noarch        27kB
  + psycopg2       2.9.3  py310h5764c6d_1  conda-forge/linux-64     185kB
  + pyodbc        4.0.35  py310hd8f1fbe_0  conda-forge/linux-64      79kB
  + sqlparse       0.4.3  pyhd8ed1ab_0     conda-forge/noarch        36kB

  Summary:

  Install: 6 packages

  Total download: 3MB

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


Looking for: ['ipython-sql', 'pyodbc', 'psycopg2', 'sqlalchemy']


Pinned packages:
  - python 3.10.*
  - python 3.10.6


Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Will remove 1 package cache(s).
Removing intermediate container ced464550b21
 ---> ddfbf0e82d8a
Step 7/8 : VOLUME /notebooks
 ---> Running in 6991a675e302
Removing intermediate container 6991a675e302
 ---> 1cadb017d264
Step 8/8 : WORKDIR /notebooks
 ---> Running in 44b9027d2e6d
Removing intermediate container 44b9027d2e6d
 ---> c888d15b3e82
Successfully built c888d15b3e82
```

Comment: Tried this, while running docker build . , I get this error

 => ERROR [4/5] RUN mamba install --yes --file /tmp/requirements.txt &&     mamba clean --all -f -y &&     fix-permission  7.0s

[...]

#8 6.847 Looking for: ['ipython-sql', 'pyodbc', 'psycopg2', 'sqlalchemy']

#8 6.847 Pinned packages:
#8 6.847   - python 3.10.*
#8 6.847   - python 3.10.6

#8 6.847 Encountered problems while solving:
#8 6.847   - nothing provides requested pyodbc

Comment: It seems to work when I run it but I also don't know what I'm doing as I have never used this base image before.  Can you include the full updated Dockerfile at the bottom of your question ?   My dockerfile has 8 steps.  I'm running this on linux.

Comment: @wildBass I added my Dockerfile verbatim and the cmd I used and the output, I don't know anything about Conda, it seems that it has its own environment though and pip wasn't installing the package into it